# How to copy mdb file to another location through command prompt?

Tags: dos

I'm seeking the DOS syntax to copy a access database from lets say Z:\Data\Test.mdb to C:\Temp

How can I do this?

many thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
copy Z:\Data\Test.mdb  C:\Temp
```

TIP:

When you're not sure what command to use in DOS, bring up a command prompt and type `help`. Also, if you see a command you want to know more about, you can type the command followed by /? and you'll get the help for it. For example, typing `copy /?` will show you the usage.

Comment: Anohter tip: MDB files are frequently opened with exclusive access. If that is the case you won't be able to copy the file without closing the program that has it open.

Comment: @torak - Yet another tip, to find out what has the file opened, you can use the handle.exe utility from here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx

Comment: I prefer Process Explorer from http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your operating system version, you might want to look at XCOPY or ROBOCOPY which provide some more advanced file/folder copying features.